# Unable to consume WCF service without adding reference or proxy classes

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am supposed to consume a wcf service which is hosted at a server. This wcf service is not accessible to my network. Since the wcf is not accessible to me I can not add service reference and automatically create proxy classes through in visual studio. I was hoping I could write code to access this service (even though I cant actually access it on my network) and later deploy it to the server where wcf is accessible.  Just like I could in case of web api.

I was referring this tutorial : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-WCF-Service-SVC-without-creating-Proxy-in-ASPNet.aspx

```
        private IService GetServiceClient()
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress endpoint = new    
            EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF_NewsService/News_Service/");
            IService client = ChannelFactory<IService>.CreateChannel(binding, endpoint);
            return client;
        }
```

Where do I get `IService` from? I am confused. All I have is a URL that I can not access. And A method   `string GetCustomer(string name)` present in wcf which i am supposed to use.

Comment: How are you going to call that server from your client application if it's not accessible?

Comment: @CodeFuller Eventually, I will be running the client application from a system to which it is accessible. But that is after I am done coding. As of now I have to develop the client application on my system to which the service is not accessible.

Comment: You need an access to the service for generation of client proxy code. You could use svcutil.exe for this purpose, but access to the service is still required.